# How to handle user authentication in Spring MVC/Flex hybrid app

Tags: java, apache-flex, spring-mvc, spring-security, blazeds

We have an application that is a Flex front end to a Java backend using Blazeds.  We are in the process of converting away from Flex to an HTML and JS front end using Spring MVC.  We want to do this incrementally, replacing piece by piece of flex with html.  This will mean that parts of the current flex app will become "components" on various different pages within the new Spring MVC app.

The question is how best to go about user authentication in the Flex components during this interim period.  Is there a good approach to making the Flex components hook into the same Java session in use on the SpringMVC side, perhaps some sort of SSO based approach?  We are already using Spring Security with BlazeDS.  Is this even possible?

Comment: You can check already asked question see [this][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267430/how-to-secure-a-hybrid-spring-mvc-flex-application-with-spring-security

Comment: I did check that answer.  It however is asking a different question than mine.  That question asks "I'm trying to secure both interfaces and can get each one working separately, but not together."  Whereas I would like both interfaces to work together as if they were one interface.